# Как организовать работу сайта с ботом telegram?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Можно ли организовать работу сайта с ботом telegram в таком ключе, я отправляю боту команду, а он POST или GET запросом отправляет ее на сайт и на сайте выполняется функция, заданная этой командой. Я искал в интернете, но чего-то конкретного не нашел, нашел только обратное взаимодействие, когда с сайта управляется Telegram бот.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое понятие, как WebHook - оповещение сервиса о событии.

**Регистрация webhook в Telegram**

Создаём data.json:

```
{
  "url": "https://bots.domain.tld/api/v1/echo"
}
```

И вызываем соответствующий метод API любым доступным способом, например:

```
curl -X POST -d @data.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.telegram.org/botYOURBOTTOKEN/setWebhook"
```

Ваш домен, хук на который вы устанавливаете, должен резолвится и сервер для вебхука должен быть поднят на защищенном соединении, иначе метод setWebhook не отработает.

[Подробное описание метода на официальном сайте](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)

Использованы источники: [Habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/322078/)

P.S Прекратите меня минусить из-за того, что не знаете, что есть такое понятие, как **регистрация веб-хука на вашей стороне**, который будет дергать телеграмм. На комментарии: "зачем мне дергать вебхук" - я отвечать больше не буду.

Comment: Вопрос ведь о другом. Требуется описать обратное взаимодействие: бот отправляет запросы на сайт.

Comment: @mymedia Это и есть нужное взаимодействие, отправляется команда боту через мессенджер, а бот дергает вебхук для выполнения какого-то действия (отправки запроса на сайт)

Comment: Но примеры у вас приведены для установки веб-хука в телеграмме. Это не обязательно для того, чтобы просто слать запросы на сторонний сайт.

Comment: @mymedia Укажите пожалуйста, какие еще есть методы установить адрес, по которому бот будет слать информацию о поступивших событиях? Кроме того, чтобы повесить long-poll демон на метод, ведь вопрос был в отправке данных на скрипт HTTP методом из бота.

Comment: Вот именно! А ответ у вас про другое.

Comment: @mymedia Я вас не понимаю, мы установили адрес, по которому бот будет слать ответ по любому событию с помощью data.json, и отправили его на метод setWebhook, теперь бот при любом событии будет слать ответ на указанный url. Укажите пожалуйста подробнее, что не так то?

Comment: А бот ли будет слать или телеграм? Телеграм то будет слать запросы в своём формате.

Comment: @mymedia Телеграм будет слать, что в целом равносильно боту при использовании веб-хука. Ну разница-то какая, разобрать запрос в любом случае можно :)

Comment: @Anatol Если бы вы читали внимательнее ответ, а заодно и telegram api, то тогда бы поняли, что вебхуком называется адрес на вашей стороне, а не на стороне бота. Бот вызывает установленный вебхук на вашей стороне.

Comment: @Anatol https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook - Use this method to specify a url and receive incoming updates via an outgoing webhook. Whenever there is an update for the bot, we will send an HTTPS POST request to the specified url, containing a JSON-serialized Update.

Comment: @Firepro - Вы считаете, что это ответ на мой вопрос?

Comment: @Anatol Да, я указал вам метод который описывает, что в telegram есть что-то про вебХуки, указал что он делает это через HTTPS POST, и указал, что отсылает указанный ответ в JSON. Заметьте, что также привел исчерпывающую информацию в виде ссылки на официальную документацию в которой вы подробнее можете ознакомиться со структурой посылаемой в JSON.